# Are Business Analyst Questions On Topic Moving Forward?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-topic

[Should patches which cause regression issues be accepted?](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/5774/should-patches-which-cause-regression-issues-be-accepted)

The above question has one **off-topic** close vote on it from a community user. It's asked from the perspective of a business analyst.

Should this question be closed as off-topic or will we allow business-analyst questions moving forward? Note that we're working on redefining the scope of the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd vote to close. It is not a PM question.